# get the attachmentname from 1 out of 2 rich text fields

Tags: xpages, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have a form with 2 rich text fields.
They both store pictures.
I have 1 text field to store the name of the second rich text field.
For this I'm using : @Subset(@AttachmentNames;1)
but the problem is that in this way I don't have control from which rich text field the attachmentname is comming.
Any idea ?

Comment: Are you looking for an XPages answer or is this standard Notes client only? If so, then please remove the xpages tag.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this with Formula. In LotusScript you can do something like:

```
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc as NotesUIDocument
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim body1 as NotesRichtextItem
Dim body2 as NotesRichtextItem

Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Set doc = uidoc.Document
Set body1 = doc.GetFirstItem( "NameOfFirstField" )
Set body2 = doc.GetFirstItem( "NameOfFirstField" )

If Not Isempty(body1.EmbeddedObjects) Then    
  Forall o In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects      
    If ( o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT ) Then        
      'Found attachment: add name to list
      'do something with o.Source, this is the name of the attachment
    End If
  End Forall
End If
```

Take care: The attachments in LotusScript are only current after a save of the document...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lotusscript. `RichTextItem` can contain an `EmbeddedObject`, which has property `Source`. For attachments, this contains the file name.

Quote from help file:

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim rtitem As Variant
Dim object As NotesEmbeddedObject
Dim sourceName As String    
'...set value of doc...
Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem( "Body" )
If ( rtitem.Type = RICHTEXT ) Then
  Set object = rtitem.GetEmbeddedObject( "City picture" )
  sourceName = object.Source
End If
```